# Provided key is not a valid Google API key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google map api. I copied the Hello_World.html from google maps javascript v3  getting started. But I always get the error message: `the provided key is not a valid google api key`.

I tried a few things but none of them worked. The following is what I did:

1. I edited the allowed referrers to `mysite.com/*` and `localhost/*`. But the error message is still there.
2. I tried a method someone suggested, which adds javascript version number: 
   change `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={XXX....X}&sensor=true"` to `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6key={XXX....X}&sensor=true"`, even so, the error message is still there.

Can someone give me any suggestions?

Comment: You don't _need_ a key, it should work without it.  where did you get the key from? This `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6key={XXX....X}&sensor=true` is incorrect.  1. it is missing an & between the v=3.6 and "key".  2. version 3.6 is no longer available, that will result in the ["frozen version"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), currently version 3.11.

Comment: @geocodezip your comment should probably be an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The key provided is not a valid Google API Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966668/the-key-provided-is-not-a-valid-google-api-key)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a key for Google Maps API v3, [see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3#newkey). Your API v2 key will not work. 
You will only need key for API v3 in case you want some additional features (very high traffic site, additional statistics etc.). But this is a very rare case.

Comment: Hi Tomas, Thank you for your help. I got the key from: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/…. I assume that only Google Maps API for business does not need key. I even tried not use API key and not use v-3.6, but the google map can not be loaded. Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: @user2525034, as I said, for normal use you don't need the key.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* a key, it should work without it. If you provided the key you are using (it isn't secret and can't be used on domains that you don't allow), we could tell if it is at least the correct format.

This

> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6key={XXX....X}&sensor=true

is incorrect.

1. it is missing an & between the v=3.6 and "key".
2. version 3.6 is no longer available, that will result in the "frozen version", currently version 3.11.

Comment: Hi geocodezip, Thank you for your help. I got the key from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key. I assume that only Google Maps API for business does not need key. I even tried not use API key and not use v-3.6, but the google map can not be loaded. Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) says "All Maps API applications* **should** load the Maps API using an API key. Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary. If your application's Maps API usage exceeds the Usage Limits, you must load the Maps API using an API key in order to purchase additional quota.", it is only required if you need to pay for additional quota.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The solution is:

1. Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console -> api access
2. Click "Key for browser apps".
3. The example says to enter `*.example.com/*` but it doesn't work for me. I had to enter (one per line):

   ```
   example.com   
   *.example.com
   *.example.com/*
   example.com/*
   ```

Hope this helps