# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - Getting Started

Tags: google-maps

I copy-pasted an example from the [Google Maps Get Started page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)
into Notepad and include my newly created API key.

When I run it, it gives me the error:

> google disable use of the map API for this application. The provided key is not valid google API key

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you referred this question [google api key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966668/the-key-provided-is-not-a-valid-google-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

What API version are you using v2 or v3 ? A key for V3 is not necessary to start.
Perhaps did you mix a v2 key with a v3 key or vice-versa ?
Please paste / copy the code you use.